# Displaying image from sqlite database in android?

Tags: android

I want to display images from sqlite database in my application. My requrement is to display a textview and its related image. I kept my database file in assets folder. 
But actually my images are stored in "allimages" folder in the server.

My database columns(db in assets folder which I kept) is as:

S.No    Description

1         div style="text-align: justify;">Gandhiji is a great leader img height="194" width="281" src="/allimages/img.png" alt="" div

2         div style="text-align: justify;">Subash is a great leader img height="194" width="281" src="/allimages/img.png" alt="" /> 

-           -------------
-           ------------
-           ------------
--          ------------
-          -----------------

**Now my problem is in my database the image path is stored as I shown in description column. In android we cannot create a new folder in drawable folder and refer the path of the image. My databse consists of 2000 to 3000 records. Now I cant change the path of the image in my local database. So where should I create "allimages" folder in my project folder and how can I refer those images? Anybody please help me to solve this issue.....I am struggling with this issue...**

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: I don't quite understand because I'm not sure how you would get the images using a relative path if they are on a server? But, why can't you modify the path after you retrieve the description from the DB? It wouldn't be hard to modify *src="/allimages/img.png"* with *src="/some/other/path/allimages/img.png*?

Comment: Hi actually the images are on a server. But now I will keep them locally. To put locally I need to create a folder "allimages" because my local database description column consists of that path src="/allimages/img.png" only na...So what should I do? Is it possible to change the path of image in my local db? If so how can I change the path of image for 1000's of records?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments above:

**You can update all the elements in a database through a loop**

It looks like your descriptions are unique, so unfortunately, you'll need to extract the data from the database, put it into some sort of list, modify the list to change the path, then update the databse with the modified values.

Note: You would only need to do this one time, but if you have thousands of records to update, it will take time.

Below is some pseudo-code of the steps you'll need to perform to update all the paths.

*Fetch all the records, extract the data and modify the path*

```
//Get all the records
Cursor allRecords = database.query(Table_Name, null, null, null, null, null, null);

//Extract the data from the Cursor and create a list
List<SomeDataObject> listOfModifiedDataObjects = new ArrayList<SomeDataObject>();

allRecords.moveToFirst();

while(!allRecords.isAfterLast())
{
    int id = allRecords.getInt(allRecords.getColumnIndex("NameOfIDColumn"));
    String description = allRecords.getString(allRecords.getColumnIndex("NameOfDescriptionColumn"));

    //Modify the description to change the path of the src...
    description = description.replace("allimages", "some/other/path/allimages");

    //Create the data object and store it in the list
    SomeDataObject tempObj = new SomeDataObject();
    tempObj.ID = id;
    tempObj.Description = description;

    listOfModifiedDataObjects.add(tempObj);

}
```

*Update the databse with the modified data*
Note: This should be done in some database helper class that has access to the SQLiteDatabase object

```
//Iterate through all the modified data objects
for(SomeDataObject curObj: listOfModifiedDataObjects)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Set the new description into the content values object
    values.put("NameOfDescriptionColumn", curObj.Description);

    //Update the table with the new value. The record that gets updated is based on the curObj.ID.
    //In this case, I'm guessing your id column is named "_id"
    database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.ValueOf(curObj.ID)});
}
```

I haven't compiled any of this code and don't have an IDE handy, so there may be minor typos. But hopefully that gives you a general idea of how to update each record.